# apple llvm compiler 4.0 error

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4

having problems while building my app.
I am guessing the error is not related to app logic,as I am newbie in ios programming, could not understand the error.

```
CompileC /home/stu9/s7/pbd6595/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/calorieCalculator-    aqrcctfytdkkduhjvhqewuibvnuf/Build/Intermediates/calorieCalculator.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/calorieCalculator.build/Objects-normal/i386/calorieCalculatorViewController.o calorieCalculator/calorieCalculatorViewController.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
cd /home/stu9/s7/pbd6595/Documents/MC/calorieCalculator/calorieCalculator
setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -arch i386 -fmessage-length=0 -std=gnu99 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wreturn-type -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wduplicate-method-match -Wformat -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wno-undeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DDEBUG=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk -fexceptions -fasm-blocks -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -g -Wno-sign-conversion -fobjc-abi-version=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch "-DIBOutlet=__attribute__((iboutlet))" "-DIBOutletCollection(ClassName)=__attribute__((iboutletcollection(ClassName)))" "-DIBAction=void)__attribute__((ibaction)" -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=50100 -iquote /home/stu9/s7/pbd6595/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/calorieCalculator-aqrcctfytdkkduhjvhqewuibvnuf/Build/Intermediates/calorieCalculator.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/calorieCalculator.build/calorieCalculator-generated-files.hmap -I/home/stu9/s7/pbd6595/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/calorieCalculator-aqrcctfytdkkduhjvhqewuibvnuf/Build/Intermediates/calorieCalculator.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/calorieCalculator.build/calorieCalculator-own-target-headers.hmap -I/home/stu9/s7/pbd6595/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/calorieCalculator-aqrcctfytdkkduhjvhqewuibvnuf/Build/Intermediates/calorieCalculator.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/calorieCalculator.build/calorieCalculator-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /home/stu9/s7/pbd6595/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/calorieCalculator-aqrcctfytdkkduhjvhqewuibvnuf/Build/Intermediates/calorieCalculator.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/calorieCalculator.build/calorieCalculator-project-headers.hmap -I/home/stu9/s7/pbd6595/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/calorieCalculator-aqrcctfytdkkduhjvhqewuibvnuf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/home/stu9/s7/pbd6595/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/calorieCalculator-aqrcctfytdkkduhjvhqewuibvnuf/Build/Intermediates/calorieCalculator.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/calorieCalculator.build/DerivedSources/i386 -I/home/stu9/s7/pbd6595/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/calorieCalculator-aqrcctfytdkkduhjvhqewuibvnuf/Build/Intermediates/calorieCalculator.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/calorieCalculator.build/DerivedSources -F/home/stu9/s7/pbd6595/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/calorieCalculator-aqrcctfytdkkduhjvhqewuibvnuf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -include /home/stu9/s7/pbd6595/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/calorieCalculator-aqrcctfytdkkduhjvhqewuibvnuf/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/calorieCalculator-Prefix-gglwlmdmlndtxwahlpktkqstdeev/calorieCalculator-Prefix.pch -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /home/stu9/s7/pbd6595/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/calorieCalculator-aqrcctfytdkkduhjvhqewuibvnuf/Build/Intermediates/calorieCalculator.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/calorieCalculator.build/Objects-normal/i386/calorieCalculatorViewController.d --serialize-diagnostics /home/stu9/s7/pbd6595/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/calorieCalculator-aqrcctfytdkkduhjvhqewuibvnuf/Build/Intermediates/calorieCalculator.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/calorieCalculator.build/Objects-normal/i386/calorieCalculatorViewController.dia -c /home/stu9/s7/pbd6595/Documents/MC/calorieCalculator/calorieCalculator/calorieCalculator/calorieCalculatorViewController.m -o /home/stu9/s7/pbd6595/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/calorieCalculator-aqrcctfytdkkduhjvhqewuibvnuf/Build/Intermediates/calorieCalculator.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/calorieCalculator.build/Objects-normal/i386/calorieCalculatorViewController.o
fatal error: error in backend: IO failure on output stream.
Comman/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: The important part is `error in backend: IO failure on output stream`. Are you perhaps out of disk space?

Comment: yes, I cleared up some space. its working now. Thanks Greg!

Answer (score 0):

`clang` is trying to write the object file to `/home/stu9/s7/pbd6595/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/calorieCalculator-aqrcctfytdkkduhjvhqewuibvnuf/Build/Intermediates/calorieCalculator.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/calorieCalculator.build/Objects-normal/i386/calorieCalculatorViewController.o`. Maybe `/home/stu9/s7/pbd6595` is a read-only volume on a file server ? Perhaps you need to copy the project to a directory on your local disk first ?